# Powershell Invoke command remotely causes out-lineoutput

Tags: windows, powershell, remote, windows-server-2016

I just started using powershell and i am trying to use the:

Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*"' | Format-Table Name, DistinguishedName -A

Remote here for i used

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <name> -ScriptBlock {Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*"' | Format-Table Name, DistinguishedName -A} -credential <cred>
```

but then i get the error

```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [out-lineoutput], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatObjectDeserializerNullDataMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputComman
   d
```

I have no clue what to do if i use the command localy it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Got it had to use

```
$session = Invoke-Command -ComputerName 192.168.51.128 -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*"' 
} -credential $cred

Write-Output $session | Format-Table Name, DistinguishedName -A
```

Comment: the reason this worked is that the `Format-*` cmdlets should NEVER be used for anything other than _final output to the screen_ OR _final output to a plain text file_. save the output of `F-T` to a $Var and then look at `$Var[3]` ... you will see lots of red error text AND mention of `format` in the object type.